# Looping Switch Statement

Tags: switch-statement

I want to ask:
How to use looping switch statements in a C++ program?
Like a company sells 3-4 products and we have to enter a `price` for each product in that program. And the user can also enter the `quantity`.

Then that program calculates the `price * quantity` as well as it includes GST in the end.

Comment: There is no such thing. Switch is just an abstraction of If...else if...else if.....else.
You could have 
`while(bool)
{
switch(thing)
{
case 1:{break}
default: {break;}
}
}`

Comment: But we can use nested switch statements?  Right?  Switch within switch? Can you guide me about it

Comment: No reason why not, again switch is just a shortcut for if...else if...else if....else. You can nest if statements (and by extension switch statements) infinitely deep.

Comment: I'm still having some problems. Is it possible i can private you in someway?